# How to integrate Android source code to project?

Tags: android

I am starting to develop with Android.  I downloaded [ADT Bundle for Mac](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and created a sample project.  When I tried to debug into an Android class, it says source not found.  What's the quickest, least intimidating way to get android source integrated with my project so I can debug into it?

Comment: use AndroidStudio IDE, latest version does this for you automagically ;-)

Comment: @Blundell Installed AndroidStudio, but it still requires me to attach source.  I did that and it worked now.

Comment: and makesure you have downloaded everything in the SDK manager, particularly "sources for sdk platform" for whatever api you are targeting